# Clion cannot resolve __int128_t but compiler say otherwise

Tags: c, clion

Clion said `cannot resolve type __int128_t`, but it compiles anyway.

Is this a bug, if it is, is there a way to bypass it?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    __int128_t test = 2333;
    printf("%lld", test);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Olaf Has it occurred to you that the OP meant the compiler inside Clion?

Comment: @machine_1: There is no compiler "inside CLion". It uses what you installed/configured.

Comment: What I meant is, I used clang to compile my program and it works, but inside the editor of Clion, it red line me on the type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`__int128_t` is not a standard type defined by the C Standard.  It is an extension supported by some compilers.  Your compiler seems to support it as it compiles the posted code, but you development environment does not understand it and does not find a `typedef` for it in the headers included.

There might be some configuration available to tell your environment about the compiler's extensions...

Note that there are other problems in your code:

- you do not include `<stdio.h>`
- You pass an `__int128_t` to `printf` for format `%lld`.  There is no guarantee that this is correct.  You should cast the argument as `(long long)` for `printf` to behave correctly, but type `long long` might not have the same range of values as `__int128_t`, thus printing `test` after conversion might truncate the value in a system specific way.  There might be an extended format for `printf` to handle values of type `__int128_t`, check your compiler/runtime documentation.
- You should probably add a `\n` at the end of the format string.  Some systems do not flush output in the absence of a final linefeed.